Ubuntu 24.04 App Centre - App search bar dark background makes difficult to search text
I have upgraded from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu Development 24.04 Dev release and now completely on 24.04 LTS.
The Upgrade went pretty much smoothly barring minor hick-ups which were addressed after package update & upgrades. However, the App Center search bar remains with a dark background making it difficult to view the typed text in the search bar. Any solution?
showing Dark Background


have you tried using the High Contrast setting in  Settings > Accessibility > Seeing? Set it on and off at will using the slider control.

Hi @graham, Yes I have had High Contrast theme enabled in the accessibility options. Disabling high contrast addresses the issue. Now I can see the search text. Thanks a ton!
So apparently this appears to be a cosmetic bug with the high contrast theme.

So apparently disabling the High Contrast accessibility option addressed the issue for now. Turning on the "High Contrast" to Off and then turning it back to On again will not entirely address the issue. One has to keep the High Contrast option turned Off all the time. Thanks, @graham for your input.

glad that helped - I'll post as answer if you'd care to accept it and upvote it, it may help others with the same issue to find the solution.

As reported by the user, go to Settings > Accessibility > Seeing and recycle the High Contrast flag if on and then make sure it is set to off.
If already off, set it on then back to off to recycle it.

